# Find maxima and minima of $xyz$ given $x+y+z=0$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

Tags: calculus, optimization, vector-spaces

Find the maximum and minimum value of the product of three real numbers $x,y,z$. If the sum of these is equal to zero and the sum of its squares is equal to one.

I supose the following equations:  $$x+y+z=0$$ $$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$ $$xyz=k$$

with $k\in \mathbb R$ the number to find.

So I think that I have to solve the system of equations. The problem is from a chapter of implicit derivates in vector calculus, but I don't even know if I started well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $z=-(x+y)$, rewrite the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ as $(x+y)^2-xy=\frac12$. Then,

$$k=xyz=-xy(x+y)=\frac12(x+y)-(x+y)^3$$

To find the extrema of $k$, take its derivative with respect to $x+y$ and set it to zero, which leads to $x+y=\pm\frac 1{\sqrt6}$. Thus, the maximum and minimum values are, respectively,

$$k_{max}=\frac{\sqrt6}{18},\>\>\>\>\>k_{min}=-\frac{\sqrt6}{18}$$

Comment: Another way to find $k_\min$ and $k_\max$ is using AM-GM. From $$|y+z|^2+|z+x|^2+|x+y|^2=x^2+y^2+z^2=1,$$ we may assume without loss of generality that $|x+y|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.  Let $t=|x+y|$.    We have $$|k|=\frac{1}{2}t(1-2t^2).$$ By AM-GM, $$|k|=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\left(4t^2\right)\left(1-2t^2\right)^2}\leq \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\left(\frac{(4t^2)+2(1-2t^2)}{3}\right)^3}.$$
That is,
$$|k|\leq \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3}=\frac{1}{3\sqrt{6}}.$$
The equality holds if and only if $4t^2=1-2t^2$, which means $t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$.

Comment: So the minimizing points $(x_\min,y_\min,z_\min)$ are permutations of $$\frac{(1,1,-2)}{\sqrt{6}},$$ while the maximizing points $(x_\max,y_\max,z_\max)$ are permutations of $$\frac{(-1,-1,2)}{\sqrt{6}}.$$

Comment: @WETutorialSchool - Appreciate the additional details, especially the comment on permutations to indicate multiple points for the extrema.

Answer (score 2):

The intersection between the plane $x+y+z=0$ and the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ is a circle, which can be parameterized as,

$$(x,y,z)= \frac2{\sqrt6}\left(\cos (t+\frac\pi3),\> \cos (t-\frac\pi3), \>- \cos t\right)$$

which starts at $(\frac1{\sqrt6},\frac1{\sqrt6},-\frac2{\sqrt6})$ and circles counter-clockwise over $0\le t <2\pi$. The product is then,

$$xyz=-\frac4{3\sqrt6}\cos (t+\frac\pi3)\cos (t-\frac\pi3)\cos t = -\frac{\cos 3t}{3\sqrt6}$$

which has the maximum value $\frac1{3\sqrt6}$ when $\cos3t=-1$ and minimum value $-\frac1{3\sqrt6}$ when $\cos3t=1$. Note that the extrema are reached at multiple points along the circle, where their locations can be derived by solving $\cos 3t=\pm1$.

Answer (score 1):

Try to interpret x, y, and z as coordinates in a standard three dimensional coordinate system - the first equation defines a plane, the second a sphere. You can then imagine where the sphere and the plane intersect, and how large k would be for all those points.

Answer (score 1):

By $(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)$, we find $xy+yz+zx=-\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Now let's take a polinomial function $P(t)=t^3+bt^2+ct+d$ such that real numbers $x,y,z$ are roots of $P$.

By Vieta formulas, we yields $b=0$, $c=-\dfrac{1}{2}$, $d=-k$ and $P(t)=t^3-t\dfrac{1}{2}-k$.

Now let's define $R(t)=t^3-t\dfrac{1}{2}t$. Hence, $R'(t)=3t^2-\dfrac{1}{2}=0$ and $t=\pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$. Therefore local extreme values of $R$:

$R(\pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}})=\mp\dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{18}$.

Thus; $x,y,z$ will be real roots of $P$ for $ -\dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{18}\leq k \leq \dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{18}$.